# Why {} == 1 will throw a Error and 1 == {} will not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In javaScript, such situation will happen, I want to know why ?

```js
1 == {}  //false
{} == 1 //throw a Error
```

Comment: When a statement starts with `{`, it is interpreted by the parser as the beginning of a **block** of statements, not an object initializer expression.

Comment: thanks your, but I have another about :`[] == [] //false`and
`[] == ![] //true`

Comment: See https://felix-kling.de/js-loose-comparison/#%5B%5D==%5B%5D and https://felix-kling.de/js-loose-comparison/#%5B%5D==!%5B%5D . The first case is easy: Two different objects are never equal. The second one is a bit more complex. Check out the links.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntactic limitation. `({}) == 1` works just fine.